# Is it worse in any aspect to use the CMPXCHG instruction on an 8-bit field than on a 32-bit field?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, c11, instruction-set

I'd like to ask if using a `CMPXCHG` instruction on an 8-bit memory field would be worse in any aspect than using it on a 32-bit field.

I'm using C11 *stdatomic.h* to implement a couple of synchronization methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No, there's no penalty for `lock cmpxchg [mem], reg` 8 vs. 32-bit**.  Modern x86 CPUs can load and store to their L1d cache with no penalty for a single byte vs. an aligned dword or qword.  [Can modern x86 hardware not store a single byte to memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721075/can-modern-x86-hardware-not-store-a-single-byte-to-memory) answer: it can with zero penalty<sup>1</sup> because they spend the transistors to make even unaligned loads/stores fast.

The surrounding asm instructions dealing with a narrow integer in a register should also have negligible if any extra cost vs. `[u]int32_t`.  See [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers) - most compilers know how to be careful with partial registers, and modern CPUs (Haswell and later, and all non-Intel) don't rename the low 8 separately from the rest of the register so the only danger is false dependencies.  Depending on exactly what you're doing, it might be best to use `unsigned` local temporaries with an `_Atomic uint8_t`, or it might be best to make your locals also `uint8_t`.

Footnote 1: Unlike on some non-x86 CPUs where a byte store actually is implemented with a cache RMW cycle ([Are there any modern CPUs where a cached byte store is actually slower than a word store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217528/are-there-any-modern-cpus-where-a-cached-byte-store-is-actually-slower-than-a-wo)).  On those CPUs you'd hope that atomic xchg would be just as cheap for word vs. byte, but that's too much to hope for with cmpxchg.  But almost all non-x86 ISAs have LL/SC instead of xchg / cmpxchg anyway, so even an atomic exchange is separate LL and SC instructions, and the SC would be take an RMW cycle to commit to cache.