# 8/16-bit atomics on 32/64-bit processors

Tags: c++, atomic, cpu-architecture, stdatomic, memory-model

In C++11 and C11 it is possible to use 8- and 16-bit atomics. Are there any pitfalls of using them on actual modern 32- and 64-bit CPUs? Are they lock-free? Are they slower than native-size atomics? I'm interested in both what standard says about it and how it's actually implemented on common architectures.

Comment: All of that are implementation details. But generally cpus can do atomics on less than the register size just fine. I would expect std::atomic<char> to be 32/64bit otherwise rather than using a lock to access a single char.

Comment: In a related vein, I've wondered if there are any important concerns regarding [false sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) and atomics on common architectures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no common pitfalls or any reason to expect any.

The standard say nothing about it, but basically nothing about performance guarantees in general.  But in practice, if `atomic<int>` is lock-free, it's almost certain that `atomic<int16_t>` and `atomic<int8_t>` are also lock-free.  I'd be surprised if there are any mainstream implementations where that's not true.

x86 hardware supports them directly, at the same speed as other operand-sizes.  e.g. `mov` load/store, and for atomic RMWs, `lock xadd byte [rdi], al` exists in byte operand-size as well as word/dword/qword.  Same for all other atomic RMW instructions, including `xchg` and `cmpxchg`.

Other ISAs may have minor slowdowns for narrow stores (and maybe also loads), like a cycle of extra latency for a pure-load or pure-store.  This is pretty much negligible compared to inter-core latency, and pretty minor even when a cache line is already hot.  See [Are there any modern CPUs where a cached byte store is actually slower than a word store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217528/are-there-any-modern-cpus-where-a-cached-byte-store-is-actually-slower-than-a-wo) (it's not unique to atomic operations.)

Most non-x86 ISAs also have byte and 16-bit versions of the same instructions they provide for atomic RMWs, like ARM `ldrexb` / `strexb`.

Of course for an atomic RMW, it's also safe to do an RMW of the containing word, and that can be done "naturally" with minimal extra work for a `fetch_or` or other bitwise boolean, or a CAS.  But I think most widely used ISAs have direct support for byte and 16-bit operations, so don't need that trick.