# Word Addressing in a Single Processor Cache

Tags: caching, memory, cpu-architecture, processor, addressing-mode

I've recently come across this description of a single processor cache saying that it's

"Word addressed (addresses are left shifted by 2 by adding “00” to end of address inside the processor, this implies that it can address 2^32*4 = 16GBytes of memory"

I understand that word addressing means that each consecutive address holds a word of data versus byte addressing which holds a byte of data at each address. I further understand that left shifting address by 2 means multiplying the address by 4 so we are trying to obtain multiples of 4, but doesn't that imply that each address holds a byte of data thus this is not word addressing but in fact byte addressing and the processor has logic in which we only access a word at a time despite what the memory is like?

So far I am confused on whether word addressed just means we have logic in place to access a word at a time or the actual memory is formatted in a way that each address will hold a whole word and not a byte

Comment: I forgot to mention but it's also mentioned that this single processor cache as a 32 bit address space

Comment: Is this a word-addressed cache in a system that uses byte-addressable memory?  If the whole system is word-addressable, those 2 low bits of the address don't exist anywhere, and the minimum load/store size is a whole word.

Comment: By those 2 low bits of addressing not existing anywhere you mean they're both set to 0s right since we're in a 32 bit address space anyway?

Comment: No, I mean there wouldn't be a place to have zeros.  If the whole system (not just some cache) was word-addressable, the system could address 2^32 words, but *not* 2^34 separate bytes.  The memory system wouldn't involve bytes at all, only 32-bit chunks of data.  If software wanted to use shifts and stuff to pack / unpack octets of bits into words, that's fine but it wouldn't involve memory addresses.  (And humans could think about that as accessing "bytes" of a word, but in terms of the memory system there'd be no such thing as a byte, and definitely not with each having its own address)

Comment: "word addressing means that each consecutive address holds a word of data versus byte addressing which holds a byte of data at each address" This is correct and standard usage for the terms word addressable vs. byte addressable.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_addressing, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_addressing

Comment: Most all modern computers can access data types in memory that are larger than 1 byte, including words, double words, etc..  These are still byte addressable systems: imho, no one would describe this capability as word addressed.

Comment: @ErikEidt: A word-addressable **cache** would be one that requires an RMW of the containing word to handle a byte or halfword store.  Like is common in non-x86 CPUs: *[Are there any modern CPUs where a cached byte store is actually slower than a word store?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54217528)* turns out yes, most non-x86.  But you wouldn't build one that handles 32-bit addresses for words in a system that uses 32-bit addresses for bytes, you'd build a word cache using 30-bit addresses, dropping the low 2 bits not shifting.

Comment: So this quote is weird, if only the cache is like that, a system like ARM or MIPS still could only address 4GiB not 16 GiB.

Comment: @PeterCordes, yes, I was ignoring the cache part of the question and only referring to the basic questions of terminology.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know where this description came from but nevertheless, perhaps the following helps illuminate what might be going on.

When we talk about byte- versus word-addressable memories (caches, RAM, SSDs, or otherwise) we are referring to the minimum width of data that can be referenced by an address. Regardless of the addressable width of a single location, the memory will still hold bytes, grouped together in 4s for words, or 8s for double-words, etc. Just the same as a byte is always made of bits (in modern systems: typically 8 bits per byte, but that's not always the case.)

For the following exmaples, let's assume we have 8 address bits. (Though real systems usually have between 16 and 54 address bits. None, that I know of, have full 64-bit addresses.)

With a byte-addressable memory, 8 address bits allows us to reference 2^8 locations. To get the size of memory, we multiply by the size (in bytes) of each addressed location. That gives us 2^8 * 1byte = 256 bytes

With a word-addressable memory, 8 address bits allows us to reference the same number of locations (2^8.) However, the size (in bytes) of each addressed location is now 4 bytes. That gives us 2^8 * 4 = 1024 bytes (1KiB.)

Now, the confusion starts to arise when we look at where the address bits are coming from.

Let's say I have 2 instruction sets (ISAs). Both have load/store instructions that take an address to memory. In one ISA, the instructions use byte-addressing. In the other, the instructions use word-addressing.

```
ld r1, 0x12
```

Looking at the *byte index* in memory that such a load instruction accesses, what would we expect in the two ISAs?

In the byte-addressed ISA, it's easy: the byte address is 0x12 (decimal: 18.)

In the word-addressed ISA, it's different. The 0x12 is an address that refers to a word in memory, rather than an individual byte. To get the index in memory as a number of bytes, we multiply by 4 (bytes per word.) That is to say, we shift the address left by 2. So 0x12 becomes 0x48 (decimal: 72.)

Okay, so an Instruction Set Architecture (ISA) can define how a number is interpreted - whether it's a word-address or byte-address.

Additionally, when it comes to caches, hardware doesn't behave in the neat way the ISA presents to software engineers.

For example, modern caches may present a dword-addressed, word-addressed or byte-addressed interface to the processor core (or other variations.) In a word-addressed scenario, to store an individual byte, the cache controller must first load the whole word in which the byte resides into a temporary internal buffer, update it with the byte being stored, then store that word back into the cache's SRAM array. This is known as a read-modify-write (RMW.)

See [Are there any modern CPUs where a cached byte store is actually slower than a word store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217528/are-there-any-modern-cpus-where-a-cached-byte-store-is-actually-slower-than-a-wo) for some real examples such as ARM Cortex-A15 where ARM's manual explains that updating the ECC (Error Correction Code) data for the 32-bit chunk is part of the reason for an RMW being needed for isolated byte or 16-bit stores.  (ARM is a byte-addressable ISA, unlike the one described in the question.)

RMW is relatively straightforward for a single byte. It's more complex for, say, a half-word (i.e. 2 byte) load/store on a byte-addressable memory. This is because the 2 bytes may cross a natural word boundary. Thus, it may be that two whole words must be loaded/stored to access a single half-word.

With word-addressable memory, the half-word will (only ever) be the bottom 2 bytes of a naturally aligned word, making such a 2-word RMW impossible/unnecessary. However, it would also be impossible to directly perform a half-word load/store on the upper half-word of any given word, since word-addressing doesn't allow for referencing that upper half-word directly. (Some ISAs offer separate load/store instructions to access the different positions within a word - such as load half-word/load-byte instructions that take a word address and an index within the word.)

Going back to the cache: On the other side of the cache (the interface to main memory or other layers of cache), neither byte- nor word-addressing are used. Instead, row-addresses are used, where a row may be 64, 128 or more bytes in size.

So, what's the point of all this? At the end of the day, it all comes down the physical hardware resources. If you know that something is word-addressed, you don't need to store the bottom 2 bits of the address because (if they were needed at all) they are guaranteed to always be zero. We can save silicon by not storing/communicating more bits than necessary. We can also simplify hardware logic by knowing certain scenarios are impossible (such as the split half-word load/store described earlier.) Knowing they're impossible cases means we don't need logic (i.e. hardware) to handle them.

Additionally, if you consider the bits needed to encode an instruction (in either of the earlier 2 ISA examples), by using word-addressing, the ISA can access (/address) more memory without needing more encoding bits per instruction.

Word-addressing also offers other practical benefits. Ask yourself, why don't we have "bit addressing"? Most memory cannot be accessed on a bit-by-bit or byte-by-byte basis. At best, a whole word or whole row must be loaded/stored. So word-addressing saves hardware the effort of masking off the bottom two address bits, loading a word, then masking&shifting the loaded word to make it align to the address.

For loads/stores, the issue of word- versus byte-addressing also overlaps with the issue of (natural) alignment of the address. But that's a topic for another question.

Comment: AFAIK, all ISAs that provide byte stores at all make them thread-safe.  If an RMW cycle to update the containing word in cache is necessary, it won't *visibly* step on stores from another core (or DMA from a device).  So the RMW cycle has to be inside the cache, holding on to MESI ownership of the cache line for the duration, not just something the core does which the cache isn't aware of.  (Unless you're on a single-core system with DMA that isn't cache-coherent.)  See [Can modern x86 hardware not store a single byte to memory?](//stackoverflow.com/q/46721075) (which covers non-x86 as well)

Comment: Agreed in so far as it's ownership of the word in cache (and thus across all caches) that facilitates the behaviour. Where that logic actually sits in hardware is variable and matters little. Apologies, my answer was aimed at illustrating the work involved, rather than an in-depth description of the optimised operation of a byte store by RMW.

Comment: Yeah, I did upvote it since it walks through the relevant concepts. But I worry that simplified explanations can give rise to misconceptions about more "advanced" topics (or worse, support existing ones).  Sometimes it's possible to choose phrasing that's still simple but avoids implying anything technically incorrect even without bringing up the other thing (like atomicity and thread-safety for the surrounding bytes).

Comment: So I might say something like "the <s>core</s> *cache controller* must first load or access the containing word...", to imply that this happens inside the cache controller's logic, not like data load/store operations from the core (which could be separated from each other by the length of the store buffer, on CPUs that have one.)  On a simple CPU without a store buffer, the mental picture readers get is essentially the same, and if they're not thinking about thread-safety then that complication isn't brought up at all.  But if they do, the phrasing guides them the right way.

Comment: I made an edit with my suggestion.  Feel free to roll back or edit further if you have a different idea you like better.