# Are RISC-V SH and SB instructions allowed to communicate with the cache?

Tags: caching, memory, cpu-architecture, riscv, cpu-cache

Are risc-v instructions such as sb and sh allowed to access the cache? Or does it communicate directly with the main memory? I have seen the Wstrb event in main memory structures, but generally not in caches. Does this depend on whether the person is programming with Verilog? I don't ask because sw will already be 32 bit, but sb and sh confuse me.

I will program cache based on the answer given.

Answer (score 0):

Cache should see informations about the operation such as address, store/load, width of the operation and store data. Caches make this strobe operation inside, by looking at the offset of the address and the width of the operation.

Comment: Even if the addresses are intermediate in the 32-bit direct mapped cache, only 32 bits are pulled from memory at the same time. In single-memory lines, it would be difficult to pull intermediate values at once. If each line was 4 and a multiple of 4, pulling 2 or writing data to the 2nd address, in short using lh and sh, would create problems in a single-memory system. Wouldn't it be necessary to create 4 different memory blocks for this? In the examples on the internet, there is only one memory line for this.

Comment: I didn’t understand about your main topic but system should be byte accessable. That’s why 32bit integer addresses goes like 0x00014 0x00018 etc. 

I mean there isn’t a word in an address as 0x00015, but if the operation is LW, you can ignore, or not. If a request comes to memory system and offset and optype(B,H,W) are not suitable for each other, that is a case called misaligned access. Most of the time, compilers won’t make this mistake but you can check: https://groups.google.com/a/groups.riscv.org/g/hw-dev/c/F8tWQ2A-vd0

Answer (score 0):

Narrow stores to cacheable memory might need to RMW the containing word of cache to update the ECC granule; most non-x86 microarchitectures do that, at least if the store buffer can't merge multiple stores into a full ECC word: See *[Are there any modern CPUs where a cached byte store is actually slower than a word store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217528/are-there-any-modern-cpus-where-a-cached-byte-store-is-actually-slower-than-a-wo/54225485#54225485)*

Evicting the cache line and bypassing cache would not be a normal design; programmers and compilers expect that byte stores are reasonably fast.

Same for unaligned word stores, which RISC-V requires to be supported. (But it allows support to be very slow, via trapping to a fault handler.  IDK how many real RISC-V designs just trap vs. having some kind of hardware support for unaligned loads and/or stores.)

Comment: I kind of understood what you said. I'm designing an architecture that has align on RISC-V. I've always had problems with cache. Even RISCOF said that it worked correctly when there was cache, but I had problems when testing with uart. Is there any code written just for cache errors? Or ready-made assembly instructions written with the riscv instruction set?

Comment: @KamerKırali: I don't know what you mean.  Verilog "code" to for logic inside the CPU that handles cache ECC errors, repairing and optionally reporting single-bit errors, and detecting other errors and raising an exception?  For ready-made asm instructions, yes, of course there are lots of existing RISC-V programs.  Many of which use byte loads and stores.  You can create one with a compiler, e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/hGso5oM4o